# Runtime Error 1004 Message - Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: excel, vba, office365

I am hoping that someone can help with a

> Runtime Error 1004 Message - Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class.

I have encountered 2 issues both concerning this error code.

I have a file which contains a user form via which I could easily add and amend records. Since I recently upgraded to a Surface Pro 7 I have been forced to use MS 365 via my MS account. Like many others, many of my files have been impacted by the missing tools and functions in Excel 365- 64 bit. By choosing to install the 32 bit version I have been able to recover these tools and functions however, I still have some issues.

Issue 1 - This error occurs when I try to enter a numeric value into the LookUp Textbox in the user form. Whilst this was not a problem with a previous version of Excel it is with MS 365. To circumvent this I have been required to convert all lookup values to a text format. Not great but it works.

Having fixed this now a further problem has arisen which returns the same Run time error and message.

Issue 2 - My user form uses frames to separate different information groups and I have set the tabs to move in the correct sequence. So I initialize the user form and completed the required details and the lookup cells work perfectly. I use a command button to add the record to the worksheet and to clear and set the user form as if just opened.

I set about entering new details in the "cleared" form and have no problems until I tab to the third frame, which contains the lookup textboxes. Before I can enter any information I get the same runtime error.

There are 5 such lookup textboxes but when I check the debug in the code it is the code for the last of these textboxes that is highlighted. I have yet to isolate this textbox to see if the error still appears, with the debug highlighting the next last code.

It seems illogical that the form and code should work for the first record entered but to fail for a subsequent record, especially when the same initialization code is used for both.

Below is the lookup code (which includes a check to ensure that a match record appears in the lookup table) and the final lines of the "Add Record" command code which clears the form once the details have been added to the worksheet.

Any help would be gratefully accepted

Vlookup Code

```vb
Private Sub txtDepotCode_AfterUpdate()
    'Looks up the Depot Location and Operator information and applies this to the databasse and the user form
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Range("J2:L250"), Me.txtDepotCode.Value) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This is an invalid code", 0, " Validation Check"
        Me.txtDepotCode.SetFocus
        Me.txtDepotCode.Value = ""
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    With Me
        .txtDepotLocation = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.txtDepotCode, Sheet2.Range("J2:L250"), 2, False)
        .txtDepotOperator = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.txtDepotCode, Sheet2.Range("J2:L250"), 3, False)
    End With
End Sub
```

Add Record Code (Final Action)

```vb
Call UserForm_Initialize
cboType.SetFocus
```

Also used in commands to Initialize the User Form and Clear the User Form.

Comment: The error means the value is not found. `CountIf` is not a valid check because it supports wildcards. Here however the problem is most likely that you are counting over `J2:L250` whereas `vlookup` will be looking in `J2:J250`.

Answer (score 0):

### Lookup Using `Application.Match`

```vb
Private Sub txtDepotCode_AfterUpdate()
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Sheet2.Range("J2:L250")
    Dim cString As String: cString = Me.txtDepotCode.Value
    Dim cIndex As Variant: cIndex = Application.Match(cString, rg.Columns(1), 0)
   
    If IsNumeric(cIndex) Then
        Me.txtDepotLocation = rg.Cells(cIndex, 2).Value
        Me.txtDepotOperator = rg.Cells(cIndex, 3).Value
    Else
        MsgBox "This is an invalid code", 0, " Validation Check"
        Me.txtDepotCode.SetFocus
        Me.txtDepotCode.Value = ""
    End If

End Sub
```